# React-Router and Material-UI: Applying custom themes depending on route

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I'm new to using `Material-UI`. I know I can use `createStyles` within a component to style it, and that I can also use `createMuiTheme` to create a global theme. What I would like to do is create a theme the `createMuiTheme` way and include many different combinations of primary and secondary colors.

I'm making a web app that displays NHL team statistics. I am dynamically creating a component that displays team statistics based on `React-Router` and the page URL. For example, if a user goes to `/rangers` the page displays New York Rangers stats, if the user goes to `/bruins` the page displays Boston Bruins stats, etc...

The way I am accomplishing this is by using `React-Router's` [useLocation](https://css-tricks.com/the-hooks-of-react-router/) function. When the user navigates to `/rangers` I use `useLocation` to grab `rangers` from the URL and I plop the team name into the GET request so that Rangers stats are requested and displayed.

What I would like to do is create a `Material-UI` theme to dynamically set primary and secondary colors on the page based on which team it is. For example, I want to set the primary color to blue and the secondary color to red when the user is at `/rangers` (Rangers team colors). If the user were to navigate to `/bruins` then I would want to set the primary and secondary colors to the Bruins team colors (black and gold).

```
const Theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
          // When at '/rangers` set primary color to Rangers blue
          rangers: '#0038a8',
          // When at '/bruins` set primary color to Bruins gold
          bruins: '#fcb514'
        },
        secondary: {
          // When at '/rangers` set secondary color to Rangers red
          rangers: '#ce1126',
          // When at '/bruins` set secondary color to Bruins black
          bruins: '#111'
        }
    });
```

Is there a way to dynamically set theme colors in `Material-UI` based on what page `React-Router` is on i.e. navigating to `/rangers` sets the Rangers colors and navigating to `/bruins` sets the Bruins colors in the theme? I would like to use `useLocation` for this in a similar fashion to how I'm doing the GET request.

I have 31 different teams/pages so doing this dynamically is much more efficient then manually creating 31 different components with different styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a way to modify your theme. In that case we would need to understand how you are rendering the components in the component tree. However, I made a simple example of operation, which you can take as a basis for your implementations.

[image: Edit Button]

Technically, you need to create a customized theme provider with Context Api so that it can be accessed from anywhere in the application. That way we can modify the theme in any component.

```js
export function ThemeProvider(props) {
  const { children } = props;

  const [themeOptions, dispatch] = React.useReducer((state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "CHANGE":
        return {
          ...state,
          colors: action.payload.colors || "DEFAULT"
        };
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unrecognized type ${action.type}`);
    }
  }, themeInitialOptions);

  const { colors } = themeOptions;
  const theme = React.useMemo(() => {
    let palette;

    switch (colors) {
      case "RANGERS":
        palette = {
          primary: { main: "#0038a8" },
          secondary: { main: "#ce1126" }
        };
        break;
      case "BRUINS":
        palette = {
          primary: { main: "#fcb514" },
          secondary: { main: "#111" }
        };
        break;
      default:
        palette = {
          primary: { main: "#673ab7" },
          secondary: { main: "#111" }
        };
        break;
    }

    const nextTheme = createMuiTheme({ palette });
    return nextTheme;
  }, [colors]);

  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <DispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </DispatchContext.Provider>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Then providing a common entry point for changes.

```js
export function useChangeTheme() {
  const dispatch = React.useContext(DispatchContext);
  return React.useCallback(
    themeOptions => dispatch({ type: "CHANGE", payload: themeOptions }),
    [dispatch]
  );
}
```

Finally, we can use it this way on the component at the top of your React tree.

```js
  const changeTheme = useChangeTheme();
  const location = useLocation();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let path = location && location.pathname.split("/");
    let team = path && path[1];
    changeTheme({ colors: team.toUpperCase() });
  }, [changeTheme, location]);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Really nice answer!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. This definitely gives me a good starting off point.